# How to Replace one Xml Node with another in C#

Tags: c#, xml

How replace XML Node from one XML document with another XML node from another  XML Document.
Please help..

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ to Xml [`XElement.ReplaceWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.replacewith.aspx) method

```
// select node from one doc
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(path_to_doc1);    
XElement one = xdoc1.Descendants("One").First(); 

// select node from another doc
XDocument xdoc2 = XDocument.Load(path_to_doc2);
XElement another = xdoc2.Descendants("Another").First(); 

// replace one xml node with another
one.ReplaceWith(another);
xdoc1.Save(path_to_doc1);
```